# Characterization of well orders by lower set property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As a very basic fact of order theory, we know that if $(E,<)$ is a well-ordered set, then all of its proper lower sets can be written as $E(x)=\{t\in E\mid t<x\}$ for some $x\in E$ (a lower set being a part of $E$ that contains every $u<t$, as soon as it contains $t$ ; it is proper, if it is not $E$ itself). Let's call this the "lower set property" (l.s.p.) .

Now, I've been having this toy question for a while : is the converse true ? Since I couldn't seem to find the answer to this seemingly basic question in textbooks nor on SE, I decided to wrap my head around it. But before presenting my attempted proof, let me explain why I'm not 100% satisfied with it, and why I need your kind advice.

**Why I find my proof somewhat suspicious.**

The thing that bothers me is unicity : a well order (or a linear order with the l.s.p.) not only has the l.s.p., but also unicity, that is, every proper lower set can be *uniquely* written as $E(x)$ - a property I'll call l.s.p.u. Now it is fairly easy to show that an order for which the l.s.p. holds is well founded. So it seemed natural to require the (apparently) stronger l.s.p.u. to show that it is a well ordering.

But then I came up with a reasoning, that seemed to only require l.s.p. That is, unicity would in fact come for free once l.s.p. is assumed ! That seemed odd to me, but I couldn't find any mistake in my reasoning, nor any counter-examples. Still, I'd like to have your thoughts on this. So here it goes.

**The "proof".**

Proposition. *Any ordered set $(E,<)$ whose proper lower sets can all be written $E(x)=\{t\in E\mid t<x\}$ for some $x\in E$ is well-ordered by $<$.*

Any union of lower sets is a lower set. Thus, for any subset $X$ of $E$, there is a biggest lower set $U$ disjoint from $X$ : namely, the union of all such lower sets. Now, I claim that if $(E,<)$ satisfies the l.s.p., and $X$ is non empty, then $U=E(t)$ for some $t\in X$. Since $U$ is proper, by l.s.p. we have $U=E(t)$ for some $t\in E$. Now $E(t)\cup\{t\}$ is a strictly greater lower set, hence it meets $X$ : that is, $t\in X$.

From that, it follows immediately that $<$ is well founded (for a minimal element $t$ of $X$ is precisely a $t\in X$, such that $E(t)\cap X=\varnothing$).

It also follows that the greatest lower set that doesn't contain a given $x\in E$ is $E(x)$ (just take $X=\{x\}$).

Now take two distinct elements $x,y\in E$. Let $E(t)$ be the greatest lower set that doesn't meet $X=\{x,y\}$. Since it contains neither $x$ nor $y$, we have $E(t)\subseteq E(x),E(y)$. And by the lemma above, we have $t=x$ or $y$. Suppose $t=y$, then $E(t)=E(y)\subseteq E(x)$. From that it is easily seen that $E(x)\cup\{y\}$ is a lower set, which doesn't contain $x$, so that it is $\subseteq E(x)$. Hence, $y\in E(x)$, that is, $y<x$. Similarly, if $t=x$ we find $x<y$.

Thus, the order is linear. Since it is well founded, it is a well ordering. And, voilà.

So, is there something I missed ? Is this in fact a trivial order-theoretic fact, and I am just re-inventing the wheel ? Or am I plainly wrong ? Any comment welcomed. Regards.

**Edit :** I have a feel I should add some more comments.
1. By "ordered set", I mean not necessarily totally ordered.
2. Along with the usual order, $\mathbb Z$ does *not* have the l.s.p : let's not forget that $\varnothing$ is a lower set ! Thus, l.s.p. implies that $E$ has a minimal element. In fact, if the only lower set for which the l.s.p. fails is the empty set, the preliminary lemma in my proof only holds for $X$ bounded below. Linearity still holds (if my proof is true), but not well foundedness.
3. The l.s.p. is definitely stronger than it looks : for instance, it *strictly* implies well-foundedness. For if you take a well ordered set and add to it an element that compares to no other, you still have a well founded order, but not l.s.p. This is an indication that indeed, l.s.p. says more than well-foundedness, so that trying to prove well-orderedness from it alone is not necessarily doomed to failure.

Comment: I just don't know why SE won't let my "Hi everyone" line in front of the post. So, hi everyone !

Comment: Before I read your proof, I would like to know what you mean by an "ordered set". Is it linearly ordered or partially ordered?

Comment: @bof I don't initially assume linearity. The whole point is to show that it follows from the assumption on lower sets. Should I edit ?

Comment: Also, I'm not a native english speaker. Does "partially" exclude "linearly", or does it just mean that linearity is not assumed ?

Comment: How about the usual ordering on the integers? It seems to have the l.s.p. but isn't a well-ordering. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Ned That's indeed the first thing I considered, before attempting any proof. But $\varnothing$ counts as a lower set ! And in $\mathbb Z$, it can obviously not be represented as $\mathbb Z(some integer)$. In fact, the l.s.p. implies a global minimal element -- it's definitely stronger than it looks.

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't think about the empty set -- I WAS missing something .